# Set plot height equal to adjacent table height through function in terms of number of rows of data in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am using the mtcars data to create a side by side plot and table in Rmarkdown.

```
---
title: "document"
author: "Maral Dorri"
date: 'May 2022'
output:
  html_document
---
```

I create a column and add the table on the right:

````
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-3">
```{r}
raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg) %>% 
  mutate(links = paste(.$id, "And <a href = 'https://www.cars.com//'>here</a>"))
tibble(
  name = raw_dat$id,
  link = paste(raw_dat$mpg, "And <a href = 'https://www.cars.com//'>here</a>")) %>%
  mutate(link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt

```
</div>
````

Then I create another column and print the plot on the left

````
<div class = "col-md-9">
```{r, fig.height=5.5}
   ggplot(raw_dat, aes(factor(id, rev(id)), mpg)) +
   geom_point() +
   coord_flip() +
   theme(plot.margin = margin(0.6, unit = "cm"))
```
</div>
</div>
````

The results are:

[image]

I know I can set the height of the figure manually and capture the same size as the table on the right, but I want to make this automatic since for my actual data, it will be changing periodically. So the function used for the height of the plot should be in terms of number of rows of data in the table.

The desired output would line up each row of the data in the table on the right with the y axis labels of the plot on the left, as shown (done manually, and not perfectly aligned)

[image]

Comment: Is it important to you that the table is an html table? Would a non-interactive table in the plot itself be sufficient?

Comment: @teunbrand, I definitely want to be able to have links in the table

Comment: This is kind of hacky, but I think it may be what you're looking for. Get the number of rows `n_rows <- nrow(raw_dat)` and then use that to set the height `fig.height=n_rows/3`. But you see that the ratio of rows-to-fig.height depends on the format of the table **AND** the user's settings. In some screens your guess of the ration will be spot on, and in others it will not.

Comment: Another solution is to use css.  You could set the height of both divs to a pre-specified height, set the image's height to 100% and let the table have a y-scroll.

Answer (score 8):

##### Update... again

Alright this will work until the plot has expanded to the point where the plot margin has scaled beyond the height of the table's header row (about 15 rows)

This is the styles and JS.

````
<style>
.main-container {
  max-width: unset;
}
</style>


```{r listen,results="asis",engine="js"}
// tbl font size is 1em (assuming-- rendered 16px; the padding t/b 8px)
// do what you're told 
setTimeout(function(){  // add to buttons
  ch = document.querySelector('.col-md-3').clientHeight; // how tall is the table
  sh = document.querySelector('.col-md-9');              // pull the 2nd column for manipulation
  si = document.querySelector('img');                    // assuming there's only one plot
  sih = si.clientHeight;                                 // plot height
  siw = si.clientWidth;                                  // plot width
  fs = $('.gt_table').css('line-height');                // size of text 
  bbt = $('.gt_table_body').css('border-top-width');     // table, head, body border (* 6)
  fss = parseInt(fs, 10);                                // strip the px from the value
  bbw = parseInt(bbt, 10);                               // strip the px from the value
  cz = sih/(sih - 11 - bbw - fss); // height of plot - margins - padding - the bottom (ticks, label, values)
  cha = ch * cz;                   // add additional height, was 1.075 before cz
  nw = siw/sih * cha;              // new width of plot
  sh.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + cha + 'px; width: ' + nw + 'px;'); // shape container for centering
  si.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + cha + 'px; width: ' + nw + 'px;');
  
  mm = document.querySelector('div.main-container > div.row'); // now get and set sizes for centering it all
  mc = mm.clientWidth;                                  // row width
  co = document.querySelector('.col-md-3').clientWidth; //  width of the table
  ms = (mc - nw - co)/2;                                // calc margin sizes
  mm.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left: ' + ms + 'px; margin-right: ' + ms + 'px;'); // center the content
}, 100) // you know, in case I'm slow...

```
````

Here's how this is in my RMD altogether.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '2022-06-08'
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
data(mtcars)
```

<style>
.main-container {
  max-width: unset;
}
</style>

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-3">

```{r tblr}
raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg) %>% 
  mutate(links = paste(.$id, "And <a href = 'https://www.cars.com//'>here</a>"))
tibble(
  name = raw_dat$id,
  link = paste(raw_dat$mpg, "And <a href = 'https://www.cars.com//'>here</a>")) %>%
  mutate(link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt

```

</div>

<div class = "col-md-9">

```{r pltr}
   ggplot(raw_dat, aes(factor(id, rev(id)), mpg)) +
   geom_point() +
   coord_flip() +
   theme(plot.margin = margin(0.6, unit = "cm"))
```

</div>
</div>


```{r listen,results="asis",engine="js"}
// tbl font size is 1em (assuming-- rendered 16px; the padding t/b 8px)
// do what you're told 
setTimeout(function(){  // add to buttons
  ch = document.querySelector('.col-md-3').clientHeight; // how tall is the table
  sh = document.querySelector('.col-md-9');              // pull the 2nd column for manipulation
  si = document.querySelector('img');                    // assuming there's only one plot
  sih = si.clientHeight;                                 // plot height
  siw = si.clientWidth;                                  // plot width
  fs = $('.gt_table').css('line-height');                // size of text 
  bbt = $('.gt_table_body').css('border-top-width');     // table, head, body border (* 6)
  fss = parseInt(fs, 10);                                // strip the px from the value
  bbw = parseInt(bbt, 10);                               // strip the px from the value
  cz = sih/(sih - 11 - bbw - fss); // height of plot - margins - padding - the bottom (ticks, label, values)
  cha = ch * cz;                   // add additional height, was 1.075 before cz
  nw = siw/sih * cha;              // new width of plot
  sh.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + cha + 'px; width: ' + nw + 'px;'); // shape container for centering
  si.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + cha + 'px; width: ' + nw + 'px;');
  
  mm = document.querySelector('div.main-container > div.row'); // now get and set sizes for centering it all
  mc = mm.clientWidth;                                  // row width
  co = document.querySelector('.col-md-3').clientWidth; //  width of the table
  ms = (mc - nw - co)/2;                                // calc margin sizes
  mm.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left: ' + ms + 'px; margin-right: ' + ms + 'px;'); // center the content
}, 100) // you know, in case I'm slow...

```
````

##### Update

I didn't realize that you wanted the labels to align between the plot and the table. Sorry about that. This updated JS will create the desired effect.

````
```{r listenOrElse,results="asis",engine="js"}

// do what you're told
setTimeout(function(){  // add to buttons
  ch = document.querySelector('.col-md-3').clientHeight;
  sh = document.querySelector('.col-md-9');
  si = document.querySelector('img'); // assuming there's only one!
  sih = si.clientHeight;
  siw = si.clientWidth;
  cha = ch * 1.075;   // add additional height, to account for plot padding
  nw = siw/sih * cha; // new width of plot
  console.log(ch);
  sh.style.height = cha + 'px';
  si.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + cha + 'px; width: ' + nw + 'px; padding-top: 5px;');
}, 100) // you know, in case I'm slow...

```
````

[image]

##### Originally wrote

If you want the exact height of `col-md-3` and `col-md-9` to be the same, you could use JS.

The first thing I'll point out is that the `max-width` of the main container is a problem. I really suggest that you either unset this or change the value. I think it's set to 960 px. You can change the main container `max-width` property with styles.

```
<style>
.main-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
</style>
```

Ensuring that the columns are the same height:

````
```{r listenOrElse,results="asis",engine="js"}

// do what you're told
setTimeout(function(){  
  ch = document.querySelector('.col-md-3').clientHeight; // get table height
  sh = document.querySelector('.col-md-9');
  si = document.querySelector('img');                // assuming there's only one!
  sih = si.clientHeight;
  siw = si.clientWidth;
  nw = siw/sih * ch;             // new width of plot (maintain aspect-ratio)
  sh.style.height = ch + 'px';   // change height of container
                                 // change height and width of plot
  si.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + ch + 'px; width: ' + nw + 'px');
}, 100) // you know, in case I'm slow...

```
````

[image]

Comment: Where does this chunk go? and how can i customize this to take account margins of the plot? I want to line up every y-axis label with the row of the table on the left.

Comment: also the `<style>
.main-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}
</style>` works for the rest of my markdown but doesnt actually affect the table and plot at all.

Comment: @Brani, is it the issue about the decimal/thousand operators? If so, on it now! As for this question, If what Brani mentioned is right (which, ya, probably!) let me take another look at this so that these labels align. (I need to account for the padding around the plot.) To answer your question about the JS chunk—it can go anywhere in your RMD. I tend to put them at the end. However, it doesn't matter. As far as the styles, without the JS, it may not make a difference.

Comment: @Maral Dorri, I've updated my answer so the labels align.

Comment: @Kat try with different numbers of table rows, e.g `mtcars[1:5, ]`, `mtcars[1:30, ]` to see if it still works as expected. According to OP: _"I want to make this automatic since for my actual data, it will be changing periodically"_

Comment: @Kat, thank you for your response, I am still not getting the full width for this side by side columns, the remaining of my code is full width but these plots are not. I wanted to make sure, where does the JS code chunk that you wrote goes, before my chunks for the table and plot or after, inside the <div> class or outside???

Comment: I've updated the file again-- along with some changes, I've also added the entire code for my RMD so that you can see how the code, chunks, and tags are placed in the file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `bstfun` package offers a nice automatic approach for this. (Note the package relies on a variety of other packages, like `magick` and `webshot`.)

```
library(patchwork)
# devtools::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun")
library(bstfun)
as_ggplot(my_table) + my_plot
```

If it's ok to be approximate, you can get the table and axis names roughly aligned using:

```
as_ggplot(my_table) | (plot_spacer() / my_plot) +
  plot_layout(heights = c(1,90)) # manual adjustment
```

[image]

Source data

```
library(gt); library(tidyverse)
raw_dat <- mtcars[1:15, ] %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% select(id, mpg) %>% 
  mutate(links = paste(.$id, "And <a href = 'https://www.cars.com//'>here</a>"))
my_table <- tibble(
  name = raw_dat$id,
  link = paste(raw_dat$mpg, "And <a href = 'https://www.cars.com//'>here</a>")) %>%
  mutate(link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt

my_plot <- ggplot(raw_dat, aes(factor(id, rev(id)), mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0.6, unit = "cm"))
```